# Centering a Scrollview which is loaded by navigation controller

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

In one of the projects I'm working on I have created a `scrollview` that is few pixels larger than the view which it is embedded in. I use a `navigation view controller` to load the view. When the animation for the `navigation view controller` finishes, it appears that the `scrollview` is no longer at the center of its embedded view. Despite centering the `scrollview` in Interface Builder, the `scrollview` is shifted a few units down when the view displays. However when one scrolls the `scrollview`, the `scrollview` tends to shift upwards. If the `scrollview` has shifted upwards and the back button of `navigation view controller` is pressed, the app terminates and gives a bad access error. How can I force the `scrollview` to remain at the center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the offset as the y coordinate changed. Thus, keeping the scrollview fixed.